# Find the Sum for odd number Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to find out how to do sum for odd number in the range from start num to end num  • Your JavaScript program must print all of the numbers beginning with the starting number that the user entered and end at the average of the two ending numbers that the user has entered • For any number that is divisible by 4, print the number AND the word "Hello!!!", otherwise just print the number • Your must also print the sum of all of the odd numbers that you are printing Here is My code:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#button").on("click", function(){
        var startnum = parseInt($("#startnum").val() );
        var endnum1 = parseInt($("#endnum1").val() );
        var endnum2 = parseInt ($("#endnum2").val() );
        var msg = " ";
        var sum = 0;


        if (endnum1>endnum2){
            for ( i = startnum ; i <= endnum1; i++){
               // modulus      
                if  (i % 4 == 0 ) {
                    msg+= "<div>" + i + " Hello!!! </div>";
                }
                else  {
                    msg+= "<div>" + i + "</div>"
                }
            } //end for loop
            
          
        } // end if 
        else {
            for ( i = startnum ; i <=endnum2; i++){
                if (i % 4 == 0){
                    msg+= "<div>" + i + " Hello!!! </div>"; 
                }
                else {
                    msg+= "<div>" + i + "</div>" 
                }
            } // end for loop
        } // end else
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYixF.png) This is sample output. How can I find a sum of odd number. my code so far in attached

Comment: Provide HTML code please.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the HTML code, I produced output by printing it to the console. I hope you can take the processes here and adapt them to your own code.

```js
 $(document).ready( function() {
        var startnum = parseInt(2)
        var endnum1 = parseInt(12);
        var endnum2 = parseInt (30);
        var msg = " ";
        var sum = 0;
        var avg=(endnum1+endnum2)/2;
        var sumOfOdds=0;

            for ( i = startnum ; i <= avg; i++){
               // modulus   
                if(i%2!=0) //oddnumber
                  sumOfOdds+=i;
                if  (i % 4 == 0 ) {
                    console.log(i , " Hello!!!") 
                }
                else  {
                    console.log(i)
                }
            } //end for loop
            
          console.log("The sum of odd numbers",sumOfOdds)
        
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```